# UITableViewController inside UIPageViewController, How to prevent diagonal dragging

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer, uipageviewcontroller

I have a UIPageViewController that scrolls horizontally different instances of a UITableViewController class.

I need to detect the direction the user drags and lock the other direction, because at the moment it is possible to scroll in any direction, that is, the uipageview in the horizontal direction and uitableview in the vertical direction at the same time.

I'm looking for a behavior like the weather app, where you are either scrolling horizontally or vertically.

This is the wrong behavior that I have atm: http://gfycat.com/LeafyWigglyGaur

Comment: I created a weather app using a UICollectionView controller with each cell set to the same size as the screen, horizontally scrolling, with UIScrollvViews and UITableViews within each cell. Diagonal scrolling doesn't appear to effect the collection view.

Comment: Gonna give it a try tomorrow if there is no better solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched to UICollectionView from UIPageView and like it still didn't work. Maybe it's my view setup I don't know.

However it ended up working after I subclassed UICollectionView and UITableView, and implemented the following UIGestureRecognizer delegate method on both:

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {

    if ([gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UIPanGestureRecognizer class]] && [otherGestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UIPanGestureRecognizer class]] ) {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

the two uiscrollviews that implement this should have scroll direction locked

Comment: It's not good solution, because if you enable tableviewcell swiping to delete, this solution will not satisfy.  but I have no better one